# I need a grid with 7 equally spaced columns

Tags: slds, slds-grid, lightning-layouts

I'm trying to use lightning-layout and lightning-layout-item to get a row with 7 equally spaced columns (no matter the contents) that fills the full width of the container.

slds-grid is useless because 7 columns don't factor very well to the 12 system.

This is for a calendar, where I'll be stacking the weeks. Any given week looks OK, but when stacked, it's obvious that the dates with 2 chars are a bit wider than the ones with 1 char.

I'm hoping to stick with lightning/slds rather than jumping over to html/css.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try slds-size_1-of-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SLDS, you can specify [sizes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/) of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 12 columns. In your specific example, you would use `slds-size_1-of-7` over all 7 columns in order to generate the appropriate layout.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had been reading all about grid and was thinking in terms of 12 and factors. Sorry to miss something so clearly documented...

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c Not entirely your fault, the original factors didn't include 5, 7, or 8 (if I recall correctly).